# How to add a Certificate to an azure service fabric cluster vmset

Tags: azure-service-fabric, azure-vm-scale-set

I have a Service Fabric cluster with a vmset based on a key-vault for its secrets. It runs fine, but now I need to add a certificate to the personal stores on the running instances (by preference without doing it manually in RDP). I used powershell to add the certificate to the key-vault, but even after increasing the capacity of vmset the new vm does not has the new certificate.

When I try to "reimage" the existing vm's I get the error

> Failed to reimage virtual machine instance 'xxxxxxx'. Error: Virtual
>   Machine Scale Sets with extension
>   Microsoft.Azure.ServiceFabric.ServiceFabricNode cannot be reimaged.

So I though I could update the certificate on a virtual machine with the following command

```
$vm = Add-AzureVMSecret -VM $vm -SourceVaultId $SourceVaultId -CertificateStore $certStore -CertificateUrl $certUrl;
Update-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup -VM $vm
```

But it seems I'm unable to get an individual vm inside the vmset.

$vm = Get-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Name "xxxxxx"

> Get-AzureRmVM : The Resource
>   'Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/xxxxxx' under resource group
>   'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' was not found. StatusCode: 404 ReasonPhrase: Not
>   Found

Does anyone know how to add a certificate on existing vm's inside a vmset?
And what if I need to update an certificate that is going to expire, seems like I'll need to do something simular.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define the certificates to deploy in the ARM template.

Examples [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/201-vm-push-certificate-windows/azuredeploy.json) and [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/service-fabric-secure-cluster-5-node-1-nodetype/azuredeploy.json).
Relevant node: 'osProfile'.

Comment: Sorry, I did not include that I did already modify the ARM template as described in http://blog.baowebdev.com/2016/07/installing-a-certificate-from-azure-keyvault-into-an-azure-vm  What I want is to update the existing VM's, but since the VM's are inside a vmset I'm unable to get them..

Comment: What happens if you just rerun the ARM VMSS template deployment with the added certificates then? So add the section, and rerun `New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment`

Comment: lol, I was thinking I had to do more, but it seems the certificates were added automaticly after deploying the updated resource. I think this is enough then, no need for updating certificates with powershell. They reflect the ARM template automaticly, which I did not expect. Meanwhile I found a bug from Microsoft: "certificateStore": "My" should be in the template, but it gets removed in the automation script.

Comment: @LoekD Won't that just recreate the whole resource group? I am also wanting to just add a certificate to existing VMs inside my Scale Set

Comment: No don't worry. You define the desired resources using ARM. What's already there remains, what's not there will be created. There's also an option to remove what's no longer in your ARM template.

Comment: also, read this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cluster-security-update-certs-azure#add-a-secondary-certificate-using-resource-manager-powershell